# How to add PNG and JPG at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am using C# and WPF. I want to add a PNG and JPG at runtıme to an image source but I get  an exception that says:

`Can not implicitly add convert type string to Sytem.Windows.Media.imageSource`

```
using System.IO;                      //for : input - output
using Microsoft.Win32;                //For : OpenFileDialog / SaveFileDialog
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;   //For : BitmapImage etc etc


<Image x:Name="img" Margin="9,13.5,6,0.5" Source="Laugh.ico"> 


private void ac(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{       
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    // Configure open file dialog box
    dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".PNG"; // Default file extension
    dlg.Filter = " (.PNG)|*.PNG"; // Filter files by extension

    // Show open file dialog box
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Process open file dialog box results
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        img.Source=filename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but as you might have noticed, that code wonT even compile. You cannot set the image source as the filename

```
img.Source = filename
```

Have a look at the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Try this:

```
 img.Source =  new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key line is:

```
img.Source=filename
```

which should be something like:

```
BitmapImage bi= new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
bi.EndInit();
img.Source = bi;
```

As you have to actually read the image file in from disk.

Comment: img = Image.FromFile(filename);

'System.Windows.Controls.Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromFile'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for an image outside of the program, but you can try:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(dlg.File.FullName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
img.Source = imgSource;
```